# Can't show files from s3 Storage::url()

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-9

Can't say why, but I can't show images or files from s3 using Laravel 9.
Can save, bu tcan´t retrieve. Let´s see some code:

Saving the file:

```php
public function uploadDoc(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'arquivo' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf,jpg,jpeg,png,doc,docx,txt,gif|max:25000',
        ], [
            'arquivo.required' => 'Por favor, selecione um arquivo.',
            'arquivo.file' => 'O arquivo deve ser um arquivo válido.',
            'arquivo.max' => 'O tamanho máximo do arquivo é de 25MB.',
            'arquivo.mimes' => 'Apenas os formatos de arquivo PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, DOC, DOCX, TXT e GIF são aceitos.',
        ]);

        $vendor = Vendor::findOrFail($request->vendor);

        $file = $request->file('arquivo');
        $filePath = $file->storeAs('vendors/'.$vendor->cnpj.'/documentos', $file->getClientOriginalName(), 's3');

        if (! $filePath) {
            return $this->sendError('Ocorreu um erro ao fazer o upload do arquivo.', 'Ocorreu um erro ao fazer o upload do arquivo.');
        }

        try {
            $document = new Document([
                'vendor_id' => $vendor->id,
                'id_status_vendor_document' => StatusDocumentVendor::DOCUMENTO_ENVIADO,
                'file' => $filePath,
            ]);

            $document->save();

            return $this->sendResponse($filePath, 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso.');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendError('Ocorreu um erro ao fazer o upload do arquivo.', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The file is successfuly sent to the s3 under the $filePath perfectly and saved to the database:

```js
  {
    "id_document_notebook": null,
    "vendor_id": 10,
    "send_date": null,
    "approved_date": null,
    "due_date": null,
    "id_status_vendor_document": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-09-27 15:53:29",
    "updated_at": "2023-09-27 15:53:29",
    "created_by": null,
    "modified_by": null,
    "file": "vendors/43354933000190/documentos/logo-curvado.png",
    "id": 8
  }
```

To show the files, we have the following method:

```php
public function teste()
    {
        $files = Document::all();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file->file = Storage::url($file->file);
        }

        return view('welcome', compact('files'));
    }
```

and the view file like:

```php
@foreach($files as $file)
    <img src="{{ $file->file }}" alt="Image">
@endforeach
```

The HTML from this view file is:

```html
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sgfor-imagens-dev/vendors/43354933000190/documentos/logo-curvado.png" alt="Image">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sgfor-imagens-dev/vendors/43354933000190/documentos/Meu%20projeto.png" alt="Image">
```

And finally, the Inspector´s window shows:

```
all-documents:2     GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/sgfor-imagens-dev/vendors/43354933000190/documentos/Meu%20projeto.png 403 (Forbidden)
all-documents:1     GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/sgfor-imagens-dev/vendors/43354933000190/documentos/logo-curvado.png 403 (Forbidden)
```

The *.env* file has all the obligated credentials and data to the *aws* section as needed.
I just don´t understand why can't show or view the files and still getting error 403.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the AWS S3 documentation got to use like this:

```php
public function getAllDocumentsByVendor($vendor_id)
    {
        $files = Document::select('file')->where('vendor_id', '=', $vendor_id)->get();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            try {
                $file->file = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
                    $file->file,
                    now()->addMinutes(5) 
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $this->sendError('Ocorreu um erro ao obter o URL temporário do arquivo.', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $files;
    }
```